# FirebaseUI Auth implementation error on Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I was trying implement the basic default auth of FirebaseUI in my Android app.

When I tried to add the dependency `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:2.3.0` the Android studio show the follow error on compile:

`'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'` (When I add the FirebaseUI dependency)

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
>
> > Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:palette-v7:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35
>       is also present at [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:23:9-25:38 to override.`

Can someone help me?

Comment: Try to replace `26.+'` with `26.0.0-alpha1` or at least `25.3.1` and also make sure your `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are set to `26`

Comment: i have tried 26.0.1 which is same as the build tools version but not the latest one that is generated by default by android studio

Comment: Post your app gradle

Comment: Post your build.gradle file